# Why can't I choose "file type" application but only class and other file types in netbeans/java?

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

netbeans 10 and java, why can  in not choose "file type" application but only class and other file tipes.

I am very new to Java programming, lesson one, Netbeans 8 did not work with JDK 11 so I got netbeans 10. Here when making a new project I want to choose java application but application is the only filetype missing soo it seems. Do I have to choose class or can somebody explain it? Or does somebody have the link to a netbeans 10 java se lesson 1 learning code?

Comment: your description is very vague. maybe it is better suited for the netbeans fora

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to create a project using **File > New File... > Java > ...**, but that will only create a new file. If that is what you are doing then instead use **File > New Project... > Java > Java Application** to create a new project.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is currently undergoing a major change of ownership which means among other things that features are missing for now.

Download an older version of Netbeans with the JDK *included* and use that.

Comment: This approach prevents the use of JDK 11, and there is no reason to believe that this would resolve the OP's issue. While there are some feature limitations with NetBeans 10, creating a Java project is certainly not one of them, and the OP's problem is likely just a lack of understanding on how to create a NetBeans project.

Comment: @skomisa there is no differences for a beginner between java 8 and 11. I am not familiar enough with Netbeans to say if op uses it incorrectly or the feature is missing. I would suggest you write a better answer.